# JSON data manipulation using ruby

Tags: ruby, json, key-value

I have a json file that I want to search using ruby and remove the key-value pair by identifying any one key out of a particular set of keys. I also need to rename a key wherever present in json file. I am stuck at this problem. The json file can be nested multiple times. Is DFS a good idea for traversal or I must look for hashing. I am facing error whenever I try. I am new to ruby.
Sample JSON file.

eg- here i want to delete `R_a` and `R_b` and rename `R_a` to `R`.
  The **output** should look something like this:

```
f1:{
    f11:abc
    f12:def
    R:[0 1]
},
f2: {
f21:abc
R:[0 1]
},
f3:{
f31:klm
}
R:[5 9]
}
```

for the **input**:

```
{
f1: {
f11:abc
f12:def
R_a:[0 1]
},
f2:
{ f21:abc
R_a:[0 1]
R_b:[3 0]
R_c:[6 7]
}
f3: {
f31:klm
R_b:[8 9]
}
R_a:[5 9]
R_b:[3 7]
}
```

Comment: Can you put a valid JSON?

Comment: I think it's helpful to view JSON as only a way of expressing objects.  You'll probably want to parse the JSON into Ruby objects, perform your operations with those objectes, and write that to JSON, right?  JSON is only the very beginning and the very end of the journey.